# How to use depthimage_to_laserscan package to create map?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, gmapping, depthimage-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan and the scan topic is published and when I rosbag record -o /scan /tf the scan topic is not been recorded and the map is not created. I am new to ros and also read thewiki page bit didn't understand how to do that any suggestion. I want to make a 2D map to implement localization.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246356/how-to-use-depthimage_to_laserscan-package-to-create-map?/) by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-10-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) on 2016-10-25**:
Plz anyone...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-25**:
Really? A *bump* after ~20 minutes? This is not a (slow)chat ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Download the gmapping package `sudo apt-get install ros-[version]-gmapping`. Then I would suggest launching both nodes using a launch file like so:

```
<launch>

    <!--- Depth image to laser scan -->
    <node pkg="depthimage_to_laserscan" type="depthimage_to_laserscan" name="depthimage_to_laserscan" >
        <param name="scan_height" value="3"/> 
        <param name="output_frame_id" value="base_link"/>
        <remap from="image" to="camera/depth/image_rect_color" />
    </node>

    <!-- Maping Node -->
    <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="gmapping_node" output="screen" >
        <remap from="odom" to="your/odom/topic" />
    </node>

</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) with karma: 545 on 2016-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

are you sure output_frame_id should be base_link or it should be camera_depth_frame

---

Originally posted by [q8wwe](https://answers.ros.org/users/38902/q8wwe/) with karma: 73 on 2019-01-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1